# Get total amount in an array of all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

my document in user collection is like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ca3a856d13601f9a474dca"),
    "name" : "user A",
    "email" : "userA@gmail.com",
    "transaction" : [ 
        {
            "amount" : 50,
            "type" : "CASH"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ca3a856d13601f9a474dcb"),
    "name" : "user B",
    "email" : "userB@gmail.com",
    "transaction" : [ 
        {
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "CHEQUE"
        },
        {
            "amount" : 200,
            "type" : "CASH"
        },
        {
            "amount" : -20,
            "type" : "USED_SERVICE"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ca3a856d13601f9a474dcc"),
    "name" : "user C",
    "email" : "userC@gmail.com",
    "transaction" : [ 
        {
            "amount" : 20,
            "type" : "CASH"
        },
        {
            "amount" : -5,
            "type" : "USED_SERVICE"
        }        
    ]
}
```

I need to add up all the transaction of all user with type like CASH or CHEQUE.

I tried the $sum aggregation operator but still no idea how to get it works.

**https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/**

Answer (score 3):

```
db.user.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$transaction"},
    {$match: {"transaction.type": {$in: ["CASH", "CHEQUE"]}}},
    {$group: {_id: "total", sum: {$sum: "$transaction.amount"}}}
)
```

1. First [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the transactions array
2. Then, [match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) by transaction type(s)
3. Finally, [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) all transactions, summing their amount

Comment: freaking awesome

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as a solution to it please try executing following query in MongoDB shell

```
db.user.aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $match: {
      transaction:{$elemMatch:{type:{$in:['CHEQUE','CASH']}}}
      }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
      $unwind: {path:'$transaction'}
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
      $group: {
       _id:{type:'$transaction.type'},
       total:{$sum:'$transaction.amount'}
      }
    }

  ]


);
```

Answer (score -1):

The optimal way to do this is actually in MongoDB version 3.4 or newer.
This version of mongod provides the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator which allow us to apply the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum)  operator to the array of "amount" value where the "type" is "CASH" or "CHEQUE".

But first you need to compute that array by [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter)ing the "transaction" array and using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map) array operator to return only the "amount" value.

The "cond" expression in `$filter` is a simple [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) expression also new in version 3.4.

Of course to get the total for all documents in the collection, you need to do this in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) stage and use `null` or whatever the equivalent is in your programming language as the `_id` value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
       "$group": {
          "_id": null,
          "total": {
             "$sum": {
                "$reduce": {
                   "input": {
                      "$map": {
                         "input": {
                            "$filter": {
                               "input": "$transaction",
                               "as": "t",
                               "cond": {
                                  "$in": [
                                     "$$t.type",
                                     [
                                        "CASH",
                                        "CHEQUE"
                                     ]
                                  ]
                               }
                            }
                         },
                         "as": "elt",
                         "in": "$$elt.amount"
                      }
                   },
                   "initialValue": 0,
                   "in": {
                      "$add": [
                         "$$value",
                         "$$this"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
])
```

---

Another less efficient alternative if your `mongod` version is 3.2 is to `$filter` the "transaction" array using the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subIsSubset) operator in the "cond" expression.

From there, you compute the sum of the "amount" value in another `$project` stage and return the total for all document with `$sum` in a final `$group` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      "$project": {
         "transaction": {
            "$filter": {
               "input": "$transaction",
               "as": "t",
               "cond": {
                  "$setIsSubset": [
                     [
                        "$$t.type"
                     ],
                     [
                        "CASH",
                        "CHEQUE"
                     ]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project": {
         "amount": {
            "$sum": "$transaction.amount"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$group": {
         "_id": null,
         "total": {
            "$sum": "$amount"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: InternalError: too much recursion

Comment: I can't reproduce the InternalError you are getting.